# What does it mean if Z statistic is -Inf?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, z-statistic

I have ran a Wilcoxon rank sum test to compare two independent samples. I now want to get a Z statistic to report, but when I do so, it results in `-Inf`. What does this mean in regards to reporting results? ...code below.

---

I have `mydata` and want to compare `scores` in two `classes`, `A` and `B`.

```
> head(mydata)

         score class
18001 1.019240     A
18002 1.020216     A
18003 1.021493     A
18005 1.022327     A
18006 1.018774     A
18007 1.021493     A
```

```
> results <- wilcox.test(score ~ class, data = mydata, na.rm = TRUE)
> results

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  score by class
W = 9129975, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

> qnorm(results$p.value) #convert p-value to Z statistic
[1] -Inf
```

Comment: If you need to report the test statistic along with the p-value, you would use the `W` value that's printed in your output.  That's the proper test statistic for this test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wilcox.test` function actually computes the *z* value, but then doesn't include it in the output.  If you know some R coding, it's pretty easy to modify the function's code to print out the *z* value.  I made a convenience function in the `rcompanion` package to do this.

It looks like this approach is better than using `qnorm` in that it returns the correct sign for *z*, and outputs a finite answer for very small *p* values.

```
require(rcompanion)

C = 30000:40000
D = 10000:20000

wilcoxonZ(C, D)

   ###    z 
   ###  122 

wilcox.test(C, D)

   ### W = 100020001, p-value < 2.2e-16

qnorm(wilcox.test(C, D)$p.value)

   ### [1] -Inf
```

Another approach is to use the output from the `coin` package, which will return similar results.

```
require(coin)

Value = c(C, D)
Group = c(rep("C", length(C)), rep("D", length(D))) 
Data  = data.frame(Group, Value)

wilcox_test(Value ~ Group, data=Data)

   ### Asymptotic Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test
   ### 
   ### Z = 122.48, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 5):

It means what you should have known before, namely that the p-value of the Wilcoxon test is essentially zero (apparently zero up to machine precision), so small that the function that you use to compute the corresponding normal quantile gives you -Inf. The null hypothesis of the test is rejected as strong as a rejection can be, corresponding with an infinite value of what you call "Z-statistic" (your Wilcoxon test is two-sided and you Z-statistic computation makes no allowance for that, which seems wrong, however the Inf wouldn't go away anyway).

In the first place I don't think it's a good idea to convert the p-value into a Z-statistic. The p-value has a very clear interpretation so why would you want to have this converted into a Z-statistic, which you then have problems to make sense of?